# appgyver Supersonic header image

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I recently saw that appgyver has a new service called supersonic, after reading the docs for the navigationbar it states you can use CSS to style it but does not really go into detail as to what is possible other then simple color styles etc.

What I am wondering is if you can add an image to the header bar, I know in the past they only supported such a feature in IOS but now I cant find any information as to support of this type of feature and wanted to know if this was possible in this new version

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently have an image in the navigation bar, but you could work around using an icon button.

Eg.

```
navigation-bar button {
  background-image: url(icons/cog.svg);
}
```

Please see http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/ui/styling-native-components/ for documentation.

Comment: This worked perfectly. But now the nav bar title is not centered. Anyway to center it?